# How to split a character without removing it (regex)

Tags: java, regex, string, split

I want to split a string at a certain point, but keep the character I'm splitting it at. For example:

```
Input:
a:b

Output:
a
:
b
```

Is there anyway I can use this with Java's split() method?
Thanks :)

Comment: why not just concatenate the split variable back into the output??

Comment: There are many ways to do it. You need to be more specific about `split a string at a certain point` part.

Comment: Thanks Explosion Pills, that's exactly what I was looking for yet I couldn't find that post.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `StringTokenizer` class in Java.

```
StringTokenizer stk = new StringTokenizer(inputStr,":", true);
```

This will return tokens as well as delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

Quick solution from my mind

1. First split it from the character you want to split
2. Join it with another string like this `____:____`
3. Now, split again with `____`

`____` is just a string which I am sure doesn't exist in the string. You can use anyother substring as well depending upon your use case

Order of time complexity `O(3*N)`

**For Example**

Your string is `a:b`.

1. Split it with `:`

   > String Array you get is ["a", "b"]
2. Join with `____:____`

   > String you get is a_***:***_b
3. Split again with `____`

   > You get ["a", ":", "b"] (desired output)

Just giving an idea.

Answer (score 0):

```
Scanner  = new Scanner(System.in);
String input = s.next();
for (String str : input.split()) {
  System.out.println(str);
  System.out.println(":");
}
```